# Javascript - Collect data from mongodb from multiple collections then merge into array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, merge

I want to fetch the newest object from multiple collections and save all into an array with collection name as key and the newest object as value.

How can I achieve this sequentially or async?

```
        let dat = ["test", "test2"];
        let merged = [];

        dat.map((collName) => {
          const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            db.collection(collName).find().sort({ timestamp: -1 }).limit(1).forEach((d) => {
              resolve(d);
            });
          })
          .then((result) => {
            merged.push(result);
          });

        console.log(merged);
```

The log at the end gives me an empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using async/await as:

```
let dat = ["test", "test2"];

const promises = dat.map(async (collName) => {
    try {
        const data = await db.collection(collName)
             .find({})
             .sort({ timestamp: -1 })
             .limit(1)
             .toArray();
        return data[0];
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
});

(async () => {
    const merged = await Promise.all(promises);
    console.log(merged);
})();
```

Comment: console.log prints [ Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> } ],   I also tried to .then() the Promise but it still won't resolve

Comment: You can use `Promise.all()` to get a single Promise that resolves when all of the promises in the merged array have resolved

Comment: That did it! Thanks alot, I also upvoted, but its not recorded as of now

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an async issue to me. You can wrap your code in a function and return the promise chain all the way down. This should give you the full array. Then use it as you need.

```js
let dat = ["test", "test2"]

const mergeData = async () => {
  const promises = await dat.map(async (collName) => {
    let value = ''
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      db.collection(collName).find().sort({ timestamp: -1 }).limit(1).forEach((d) => {
        resolve(d)
      })
    }).then(response => {
      value = response
    })
    return value
  })
  const results = await Promise.all(promises)
  
  console.log('results: ', results)
}
mergeData()
```

Comment: console.log(mergeData()) returns [ undefined, undefined ]

Comment: @J.Doe Sorry about that, I've made an edit and hopefully it will work for you now